# jQuery change event on buttons in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have a html table or a grid of data in a html table. Each row has a different user information and a button to upload the documents to that user. This table is built in a for loop. jQuery is always returning id of the first row.

How can I identify the button for a jquery change event to read the user id of the row where the button was clicked?

OR is there any other way to tackle this issue? Please advise.

```html
<tr>
    <td>@u.FirstName</td>
    <td>@u.LastName</td>
    <td>
       <input type="file" class="uploadResume" id="ResDoc" userId="@u.ID" style="display:none" accept="application/pdf" />
       <label for="ResDoc" class="btn btn-info mr-2" style="background-color:#336084;color:white;font-size:12px;">Resume</label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use $(this) selector of the button class:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".btn", function() {
  var x = $(this).siblings(".uploadResume");
  alert(x.attr("userId"));
  // do something
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>@u.FirstName</td>
  <td>@u.LastName</td>
  <td>
    <input type="file" class="uploadResume" id="ResDoc" userId="A1" style="display:none" accept="application/pdf" />
    <label for="ResDoc" class="btn btn-info mr-2" style="background-color:#336084;color:white;font-size:12px;">Resume</label>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>@u.FirstName</td>
  <td>@u.LastName</td>
  <td>
    <input type="file" class="uploadResume" id="ResDoc" userId="B2" style="display:none" accept="application/pdf" />
    <label for="ResDoc" class="btn btn-info mr-2" style="background-color:#336084;color:white;font-size:12px;">Resume</label>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>@u.FirstName</td>
  <td>@u.LastName</td>
  <td>
    <input type="file" class="uploadResume" id="ResDoc" userId="C3" style="display:none" accept="application/pdf" />
    <label for="ResDoc" class="btn btn-info mr-2" style="background-color:#336084;color:white;font-size:12px;">Resume</label>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What if you had multiple button in multiple columns?

Comment: it will still detect the variable according to which element with that class that has been triggered the event (in this case 'click' event).

Comment: When I tested your code out with more columns and more resume buttons with different `userId`s, it printed only the first button's `userId`, when it should've printed out the other button's `userId`.

Comment: I just tested it, and I'm afraid you're right. But, I always do this way to select the current element that triggered an event. And it works in my program.

Comment: I see now. I have put the selector at the _input_ element which has style=display: none.  It is actually the label when we clicked it. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you'll have other columns, so I wrote jQuery code to look for all the resume buttons and have them log their `userId` when clicked. The code is below.

```js
var uploadBtns = $(".uploadResume"); // the upload button(s)

uploadBtns.each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("userId"));
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>@u.FirstName</td>
      <td>@u.LastName</td>
      <td>
        <input type="file" class="uploadResume" id="ResDoc" userId="@u.ID" style="display:none" accept="application/pdf" />
        <label for="ResDoc" class="btn btn-info mr-2" style="background-color:#336084;color:white;font-size:12px;">Resume</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```